# Create KeyVault with variable name According to Branch with ARM Template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to Create a KeyVault with a variable name According to the Branch name with ARM Template.

My yml file variables like :

```
variables: 
  isProduction: ${{ eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main') }}

  ${{ if eq(variables.isProduction, true) }}: 
    keyVaultName: 'MyKeyVaultMain'
    azureResourceManagerConnection: 'Web Hosting'
...........
  ${{ else }}: 
    keyVaultName: 'MyKeyVaultTest'
    azureResourceManagerConnection: 'Test & Development'
.........
```

And task as :

```
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
    azureResourceManagerConnection: '$(azureResourceManagerConnection)'
    subscriptionId: '$(subscription)'
    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
    resourceGroupName: 'KeyVault-RG'
    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
    csmFile: 'keyvault/keyvault-template.json'
    keyVaultName: '$(keyVaultName)'
    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
```

And template.json is

```
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
       "keyvault_name": {
         "defaultValue": "KeyVault-DevTest",
         "type": "String"
    }
 },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [{
        "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
        "apiVersion": "2023-02-01",
        "name": "[parameters('keyvault_name')]",
```

which doesn't work. How can I send KeyVault name to the json template depending on the "Build.SourceBranch" value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your key vault name is defined as a parameter. You have to pass it during deployments:

```
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
    azureResourceManagerConnection: '$(azureResourceManagerConnection)'
    subscriptionId: '$(subscription)'
    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
    resourceGroupName: 'KeyVault-RG'
    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
    csmFile: 'keyvault/keyvault-template.json'
    overrideParameters: '-keyvault_name "$(keyVaultName)"'
    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
```